# How to embed inside looker studio a webapp created in Appengine when Identity-Aware Proxy is enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

So I created a dashboard in looker studio(not pro the free version) and in a page I'm trying to embed a site I created in GCP's app engine. Now in order to access the site I enabled IAP(
Identity-Aware Proxy) so only people I manually add can access it.

But now when I try to embed the site in looker studio using the URL Embed tool I get an error that says **Can't Embed due to provider site restrictions**.

First thing I've tried was to disable IAP an it worked, but I do need to have it enabled so that's not an option.

Then I tried embedding it to a google site which worked, but then when I tried to embed the site into looker studio I get the same Can't Embed due to provider site restrictions even when the site is public.

After searching I found [this article](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/10835295?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) which I've followed, I added the looker service agent as principal under the app engine's service account and gave it this permission iam.serviceAccount.getAccessToken, but still nothing. Any help will be appreciated